# Linq inside of Linq causing sequence to return no results

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Here are my classes:

```
public class XDetail
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class X
{
    public int XID { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

The ID is shared between them to link X and XDetail (one to many relationship).  I read in a file using the following linq query and shape an anonymous type:

```
var results = from line in File.ReadAllLines(file)
              select new
              {
                  XID = int.Parse(line.Substring(0, 8).TrimStart('0')),
                  Name = line.Substring(8, 255).Trim()
              };
```

This data is used to check against existing X/XDetail to make appropriate changes or add new records.  XList is a List and XDetailList is a List.

From there I attempt a fancy linq query to match up the appropriate items:

```
var changedData = from x in XList
                  join xDetail in XDetailList on x.ID equals xDetail.ID
                  where
                  (!results.Any(p => p.XID.Equals(x.XID))
                  || !results.Any(p => p.Name.Equals(xDetail.Name)))
                  select new
                  {
                      XValue = x,
                      XDetailValue = xDetail,
                      Result = (from result in results 
                                where result.Name.Equals(xDetail.Name) 
                                select result).Single() // This line is my bane
                  };
```

So I can get the results I'm looking for shaped into that new anonymous type, but when I tried adding in that Result = ... inner linq query my whole set turns to: Sequence contains no elements.  If I remove it I get the result set I was intending.  X/XDetail are really typed DataRows that I need to use in processing farther down using the matched Result, but without that Result I will need to do a later linq query to find the match.  I was hoping to do it in a psuedo-cool one step way.

I have tried changing Result to have no where clause and I can get a result, but the result I'm hoping to match on.  Is there a better way to write this or a way to get the result set working again?

Comment: What is `results` here? What's its type?

Comment: results is an anonymous type from the first query where I'm parsing that file for XID and Name.

Comment: I don't understand you are saying `from xDetail in XDetail` and `XDetail` is a class not an object filled with any data?How do you do that?(I am just asking.)

Comment: @Ateş GÜRAL - yeah I seem to have left that out in haste, it should look a bit better now.  I feel cheesy putting a line in saying list is a list of, but it helps.

Comment: Is there some advantage to calling .Equals in this situation instead of just using the == operator?  Using == is more readable to me.

Comment: Try changing your .Single to .SingleOrDefault. It is possible you are finding a row where the given x.Detail.Name isn't in your results set.

Comment: @Jim Wooley, hmmm maybe that is the case.  I was fairly certain from prior testing of my results set.

Comment: @Jim Wooley and that would be the case, the unexpected result happened and my first item in returned from the result query did not exist causing the Result variable to not work finally cascading to make my whole changeData result set have no elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your .Single to .SingleOrDefault. It is possible you are finding a row where the given x.Detail.Name isn't in your results set.

(Moving from a comment to answer so that it can be marked appropriately)

Answer (score 4):

One problem is that results is an `IEnumerable` - so you are re-querying it every time which causes the  `File.ReadAllLines(file)` to execute - effectively you are calling  `File.ReadAllLines(file)` `N` times which does not sound healthy.

Instead you want to bring this enumeration into memory *once* - force eager execution with `ToList()`:

```
var results = (from line in File.ReadAllLines(file)
              select new
              {
                  XID = int.Parse(line.Substring(0, 8).TrimStart('0')),
                  Name = line.Substring(8, 255).Trim()
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: This can still crash when the file has no lines